# Change Data Capture using SSIS source as Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, ssis

We have a requirement to fetch only change data from Source(Oracle) using SSIS Data Tool. We don't want to fetch entire data in Mapping and then do Insert/Update.

We are looking for something like e.g. Using variable and something below

Select * from  where Last_update_Date >= Variable

and Variable should get its data as 
Variable = Select MAX(Last_update_Date) from

Comment: This is a standard CDC load pattern. What problem are you having implementing it? Does your source have `Last_Update_Date` in it? Do you have a control table that stores what the last load date is? Have you opened Data Tools and created a package yet?

Comment: If you know the Oracle table structure, and know that there is a date you can check against, then you can just set up a query to the table as an OLE DB data source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the free [Change Data Capture Service for Oracle by Attunity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/change-data-capture/change-data-capture-service-for-oracle-by-attunity?view=sql-server-2017).  It will use a log reader to capture changes from Oracle and stage them in a SQL Server database for consumption by the SSIS CDC pipeline.

Comment: This is awesome if you're on SQL Server 2016 or above.

Comment: @digital.aaron It's available starting with SQL 2012.  Here's the download link for it in the SQL 2012 Feature Pack; https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580